# Rewrite $y(x) = \int_0^x xy(\tau) d\tau + 2x + 1$ as an ODE in the form of $u'(t) = F(t, u(t))$ with the condition $u(t_0) = u_0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, lipschitz-functions, integral-equations

I was told to differentiate it twice by $x$ (why not once?), so that's what I did here:

$$y(x) = \int_0^x xy(\tau) d\tau + 2x + 1$$

$$y'(x) = xy(x) - xy(0) + 2$$

$$y'' (x) = y(x) + xy'(x) - xy(0)$$

If I do $u = (u_1, u_2) = (y, y')$, and write $t$ instead of $x$, then I'll get

$$u' = (y', y'') = (u_2, u_1 (t) + tu_2(t) - tu_1 (0)) = F(t, u(x))$$

But I was told that I should get a system of ODEs and thus some matrix equation. But I don't see how we should get it here?

It is important because we also would like to prove that there exists exactly one solution in the neighborhood of $t_0 = 0$. For this, we need to prove that the matrix we get in our matrix equation fulfills the Lipschitz condition (by introducing an arbitrary matrix norm to prove it).

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: your $y'(x)$ is wrong...

Comment: If $Y(x)=\int_0^xy(τ)\,dτ$ is a primitive, then the equation can be written as
$$
y(x)=xY(x)+2x+1.
$$
There is no possibility for $y(0)$ to occur in a term of the derivative.

Comment: @Surb Why is it wrong? Should it only be $y'(x) = xy(x) + 2$? Because I remember that my Prof told me something that if I differentiate such integrals, that there's a theorem which states that (in this case) that "$x y(0)$" is simply equal to zero. But even then, I get $y''(x) = y(x) + xy'(x)$, which still doesn't allow me to create a matrix equation which does not depend on $x$ (because if $u = (u_1, u_2) = (y, y')$, then I get $$\begin{pmatrix}u_1'\\ u_2'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 1&-x\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\ u_2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @LutzLehmann I see. But then, I get as my comment above states, a matrix equation where the matrix still depends on $x$, which is not really something what we're looking for

Comment: Your derivative is still wrong, there is a product involved with non-constant factors. Why do you expect constant coefficients?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I don't understand. You mean, that because $(x Y(x))' = x' Y(x) + x Y'(x) = Y(x) + x y(x)$ I should actually get $y'(x) = Y(x) + x y(x) + 2$? But then, I get $y'' (x) = y(x) + (x' y(x) + x y'(x)) = y(x) + y(x) + xy'(x) = 2 y(x) + xy' (x)$. So our matrix will still depend on $x$

Comment: @LutzLehmann I expect constant coefficients, because I need to calculate the norm of the matrix later on in order to find out whether it fulfills the Lipschitz condition

Comment: So you only get local Lipschitz constants. This plus being a linear DE is sufficient for most claims about the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If $Y(x)=\int_0^xy(τ)\,dτ$ is a primitive, then the equation can be written as
$$
y(x)=xY(x)+2x+1.
$$
The derivatives of that are
$$
y'(x)=xy(x)+Y(x)+2,\\
y''(x)=xy'(x)+2y(x)
$$
You could also eliminate $Y(x)$ in the first equation by the original equation, but then $x=0$ would be a singular point of the resulting DE.

Comment: We indeed have to show that the solution is unique for $t_0=0$ (which would mean $x=0$ here). So if $u=(u_1,u_2)=(y,y')$ we get the following matrix equation: $$\begin{pmatrix}u_1'\\ u_2'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 2&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\ u_2\end{pmatrix}$$ So we now have to show, that $$\| Ab - Ac \| \le L \| b - c\|$$ where $A = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 2&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $b, c$ are arbitrary vectors. We get: $$\|\:\begin{pmatrix}b_2\:-\:c_2\\ 2\left(b_1\:-\:c_1\right)\end{pmatrix}\| \le L \|\begin{pmatrix}b_1\:-\:c_1\\ b_2\:-\:c_2\end{pmatrix}\|$$ So how to find $L$?

Comment: You are using a too specialized version of the uniqueness theorem. In $u'(x)=A(x)u(x)$ the solution exists and is unique as long as $A(x)$ is continuous. If you need a Lipschitz constant, take the supremum of $\|A(x)\|$ over some finite interval $[-N,N]$. This gives a different constant for every $N$, but the important fact is that all these constants are finite.

Comment: But given that we only have to check that the solution is unique in the neighborhood of $x = 0$, the way I did here is fine, too? If I take the Frobenius norm, I get $$\sqrt{4(b_1 - c_1)^2 + (b_2 - c_2)^2} \le \sqrt{4(b_1 - c_1)^2 + 4(b_2 - c_2)^2} = 2 \sqrt{(b_1 - c_1)^2 + (b_2 - c_2)^2}$$

Comment: No, not really. This is just one matrix norm, and then the smallest one. You need an upper bound for all matrix norms in some open set. You could say that starting from your computation there is a neighborhood of $x=0$ where $L=4$ or $L=10$ is a Lipschitz constant.

Comment: So what am I supposed to do exactly? To use another matrix norm here? I'm kind of confused, because I've been told that to show that the solution is unique in the neighborhood of $x=0$ it's enough check the Liptschitz condition using any arbitrary matrix norm, which is the case here: I took the matrix for $x = 0$, used the Frobenius norm and I got the Lipschitz constant $2$.